# Unable To Launch iOS App - Duplicate Bundle ID Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, xcode11

I have just updated an application to swift 5 and now when I go to deploy the app on my iPhone, it is giving me the below error (Duplicate bundle ID). I have checked and I cannot find a duplicate bundle ID. Is there a way to search for a duplicate bundle ID?

Can anyone suggest a possible solution to solving this?

Thanks

> Details
>
> Unable to install “ApplicationName” Domain:
>   com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code: -402653008
>   -- This application or a bundle it contains has the same bundle identifier as this application or another bundle that it contains.
>   Bundle identifiers must be unique. Domain:
>   com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code: -402653008 User Info: {
>       DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
>       MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE80000B0)";
>       "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011e60c81a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233  1
>   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011e64df70
>   **90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke
>   + 155     2   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001051a8385 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73    3   DTDeviceKitBase
>
>   0x000000011e64dca8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken
>   installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] +
>   1654  4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011e4c4e91
>   __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352
>   + 4165    5   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001052dba10 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK** + 7     6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001052dd652 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194   7
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6969c6c4
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12     8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6969d658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8     9   libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00007fff696a2c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597  10 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff696a35d6
>   _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363   11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff696acc09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596   12 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff698f7a3d
>
> ### _pthread_wqthread + 290   13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff698f6b77 start_wqthread + 15 ); }
>
> System Information
>
> macOS Version 10.15.4 (Build 19E266) Xcode 11.4 (16134)

Answer (score 2):

Just change your Bundle ID to a different name (just add a single character at the end of the name, for example), so you can launch and test on your iPhone.

If you haven't uploaded any versions of this app on the App Store yet, you can just use this new Bundle ID from now on, with no future complications. If the app already has a version on the store, all you should do is go back to the old Bundle ID when building the Archive to upload the app.